# How to save text in JTextArea in Java

Tags: java

I want to save text in a JTextArea but I don't want to save it in a .txt or anything I want to save it as in next time you open the file it still shows up(sort of like eclipse but that saves it in a file). But if that's not possible can I make my own file extension?

Comment: why you doesn't want to save as txt in the first place?

Comment: because that's not I want to happen

Comment: This is exactly what Properties are for.

Answer (score 0):

use a database such as mysql and sqlite